# Will I get consistent behavior when I POST to a cross-domain with javascript when using "document.forms[0].submit();"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, same-origin-policy, post-redirect-get

I understand that there are security issues (SOP, CORS, etc) with Javascript and cross-site requests with AJAX, however I'm submitting a form from one domain and POSTing it to another.  I don't think SOP applies, but correct me if I'm wrong.

The main reason I'm doing cross domain POSTs is because Base64 encoding the data in a GET string would end up with large URLs that may contain sensitive data.

- Is it generally acceptable (in mobile and desktop browsers) to use the following script?
- Will mobile browsers or any other browser get upset if I follow this redirect pattern?

code

```
<form action="https://MyotherDomain.com" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="UIDPName" value="@Model.UIDPName">
    <input type="submit" value="Redirect"  />
</form>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you trust the domain, i don't see why not. what exactly did you want to make it *"safe"* from?

Comment: @KevinB CORS, SOP... by safe I probably should have said "reliable in a cross platform way"

Answer (score 0):

I saw and use this exact pattern on production-level, enterprise websites. We use it to transfer data being sent via POST to a page of the user-facing site to another one being embedded via iframe.

Here is our exact implementation, where `example.com` is the domain of the second website:

```
<form class="js-forwarding-form" target="forwarding-frame" action="http://example.com" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="example" value="example">
</form>

<iframe name="forwarding-frame" src=""></iframe>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-forwarding-form').submit();
});
```

The `<body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">` version works the same.

There is no reason for it not to work because CORS and SOP only apply to requests started in JavaScript (XMLHttpRequest, etc) whereas here you're only triggering the submit of an HTML form. It has been tested and works on all major desktop browsers (not tested under IE8) as well as mobile browsers.

As for whether this is acceptable or not, well, you just have to remind yourself that this data transfer is done in plain sight on the browser. All values sent this way should be sanitized/validated like if it was user input.